# How to get a sample of a generator?

Tags: erlang, triq

I'm using [Triq](https://github.com/krestenkrab/triq) to write my property based test.
How can I see what kind of data my generator produces?

Let's say I have the following generator:

```
-module (my).
-include_lib("triq/include/triq.hrl").
-export([valid_type_gen/1]).

valid_type_gen() -> non_empty(list(any())).
```

I would like to examine what kind of data it generates, i.e. something like:

```
$ rebar3 shell
1> my:valid_type_gen().sample() %???
[1,b,"blah"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out, I just need to call the [sample](https://github.com/krestenkrab/triq/blob/master/src/triq_dom.erl#L1126) function:

```
1> hd(triq_dom:sample(my:valid_type_gen())).
[8,4,3,7,6,8,11,7,5,7]
```

That will generate a bunch of samples, and I take the first one.