# In Erlang's PropEr, how to get a sample of a generator?

Tags: erlang, property-based-testing, proper

I'm using [PropEr](http://proper.softlab.ntua.gr) to write my property based test.
How can I see what kind of data my generator produces?

Let's say I have the following generator:

```
-module(my).
-include_lib("proper/include/proper.hrl").
-export([valid_type_gen/0]).

valid_type_gen() -> non_empty(list(any())).
```

I would like to examine what kind of data it generates, i.e. something like:

```
$ erl
1> my:valid_type_gen().sample() %???
[1,b,"blah"]
```

---

For the same question in Triq, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440822/how-to-get-a-sample-of-a-generator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant function is [`proper_gen:pick/1`](https://github.com/manopapad/proper/blob/master/src/proper_gen.erl#L197). It returns a tuple `{ok, V}`.

```
$ erl
1> proper_gen:pick(my:valid_type_gen()).
{ok,[{{},<<>>,2},
     [{},11.690292064109402,
      {{}},
      {},18.096053885231132,u,')[\2064Wue¢±'],
     [{},-5.041761022794527,-13,
      {[],-0.9553811124968509},
      -5,'õ\232zc}:Ì'],
     <<47,5,113,69,86,216,20,142,173,57:6>>,
     '',
     {2.710196163900066,0.47155396154628,{},[],
      {[]},
      8.42398680461108},
     {[[25,
        [-10.073999184421432,5.734631070941083,
         {'æ\2367Ò§ü\233"',[30.925337851024143]}]],
       '']},
     '\031Þ\037\'\v','\214b\236']}
```